# Restangular method being fired twice

Tags: javascript, angularjs, restangular

I have the following example:

```
var loadUserWidget;

loadUserWidget = function() {
  console.log(Restangular.one());
  if (!$scope.i) {
    $scope.i = 0;
  }
  console.log($scope.i);
  return $scope.i = $scope.i + 1;
};

loadUserWidget()
```

and I get the following console.log

> Object {id: undefined, route: undefined, getRestangularUrl: function, getRequestedUrl: function, addRestangularMethod: function…}
>    cache_list_controller.js?body=1:276
>
> 0 cache_list_controller.js?body=1:280
>
> Object {id: undefined, route: undefined, getRestangularUrl: function, getRequestedUrl: function, addRestangularMethod: function…}
>    cache_list_controller.js?body=1:276
>
> 1 cache_list_controller.js?body=1:280

You can see that the restangular method is being fired twice and i can't seem to identify why.

Update:

Contorller:

```
bbControllers.controller('CacheListController', [
  '$scope', 'Restangular', '$rootScope', 'Snippet', '$modal', '$templateCache', "$window", 'Widget', '$sce', '$location', function($scope, Restangular, $rootScope, Snippet, $modal, $templateCache, $window, Widget, $sce, $location) {
    var loadUserWidget;
    loadUserWidget = function() {
      console.log(Restangular.one());
      if (!$scope.i) {
        $scope.i = 0;
      }
      $scope.i = $scope.i + 1;
      return console.log($scope.i);
    };
    return loadUserWidget();
  }
]);
```

**app.js**

```
var bbPlnkr = angular.module('BBPlnkr', ['BB', 'restangular', 'ngRoute', 'xeditable', 'ngSanitize']);

bbPlnkr.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider, RestangularProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/edit', {
            templateUrl: '../assets/index.html',
            controller: 'CacheListController',
            reloadOnSearch: false
        })
        .when('/edit/:id', {
            templateUrl: '../assets/index.html',
            controller: 'CacheListController'
        })
        .when('/invitation/:url', {
            templateUrl: '../assets/invitation-detail.html',
            controller: 'InvitationController'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/edit'
        });
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

Comment: do you have something like `{{ loadUserWidget() }} ` in your markup?

Comment: Can you share more code?

Comment: Or maybe you $watch the result of `loadUserWidget`?

Comment: @IlanFrumer made an update

Comment: @dfsq even did a full search in sublime to see where `loadUser()` is used and the only place I've used it is in that controller as shown above

Comment: Have you used the ng-controller directive in your template?

Comment: @ivarni yes I have and I have only use this `ng-controller` directive once in my template

Comment: But you also declare the controller in the $routeProvider, so you have two instances of it.

Comment: What ivarni says is correct, you should not use `ng-controller` directive, it causes the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using both the `ng-controller` directive in the template and declaring routes using `$routeProvider` there will be two instances of the controller, and they will both fire a Restangular request.

If you do

```
connsole.log($scope.$id);
```

You should be seeing two different values since there are two different controllers.

Don't use `ng-controller` when you are using `$routeProvider`.